# Converting from base to derived object while having a huge constructor definition

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Let's say I have a class *BaseClass*

```
class BaseClass
{
    public int PropertyOne { get; }

    public string PropertyTwo { get; }

    public BaseClass(int propertyOne, string propertyTwo)
    {
        PropertyOne = propertyOne;
        PropertyTwo = propertyTwo;
    }
}
```

And a child class *DerivedClass*

```
class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(int propertyOne, string propertyTwo) : base(propertyOne, propertyTwo)
    {
    }

    public void DerivedMethod()
    {

    }

    public static DerivedClass ConvertFromBaseClass(BaseClass baseClass)
    {
        return new DerivedClass(baseClass.PropertyOne, baseClass.PropertyTwo); // <-- ?
    }
}
```

Is it possible to implement *DerivedClass.ConvertFromBaseClass* without explicitly calling the constructor, perhaps using reflection? In a reality those classes have 50+ arguments passed into constructor and therefore it's extremely tideous and error-prone to write the constructor call in the converter method.

Comment: If the only way to create a `DerivedClass` is by calling a constructor that has 50+ arguments, then I think that's the only way to do it. But having that many arguments in a constructor begs the question: should some of those arguments be wrapped in a smaller component class? That is a ridiculously large number of required arguments.

Comment: Use AutoMapper to map your `BaseClass` to the `DerivedClass`

Comment: @RufusL thanks for your feedback. I understand that the constructor needs to be called but I just hope there is a way to do it in a compact way using some reflection magic. Also it's not possible to make arguments amount anymore less enormous because this is connected to some external code that cannot be changed in a foreseeable future.

Comment: @Lowkey thanks, I haven't previously used it and will look into that.

Comment: OP, let's say there were some way to automatically populate the constructor's 50 arguments. Where would this clever mechanism get the arguments from? Is there some rule that allows you to map them automatically, e.g. each constructor argument has the same name as a property?

Comment: @JohnWu you brought a good point that I forgot to mention on an original question. Yes, all the arguments are public properties of BaseClass and have the same naming (except the small/capital first letter).

Comment: This is strongly indicative of a bad design that you're now paying the price for. A class with fifty arguments in a constructor is almost certainly doing something very wrong. Can you describe the more specific problem in more detail?  There may be a way to refactor this entire thing so that it is a better class hierarchy, and this problem will then go away.

Comment: Also, the notion that converting *from a base class to a derived class* is even a thing indicates that there is some serious problem here.  You don't ever convert from Mammal to Giraffe unless you know that the mammal *is* a giraffe.  You don't ever have a cat in hand and ask "what is the equivalent giraffe to this cat?"  What problem are you really trying to solve here, because this is sounding like you are doing something very wrong at the conceptual level.

Comment: @EricLippert, thanks for providing such a great example. I've described my problem more explicitly in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53060487/parsing-xml-object-to-multiple-classes-with-different-logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the situation, you may be able to restructure your code to use Mixins instead.

First you extract an interface from base class. Resharper can do this at the push of a button:

```
class BaseClass : Interface
{
    public int PropertyOne { get; }

    public string PropertyTwo { get; }

    public BaseClass(int propertyOne, string propertyTwo)
    {
        PropertyOne = propertyOne;
        PropertyTwo = propertyTwo;
    }
}

interface Interface
{
    int PropertyOne { get; }

    string PropertyTwo { get; }
 }
```

Then instead of inheriting from the  base class, you add a field in derived class which you implement the interface using. Resharper can also do this in an instance:

```
class DerivedClass : Interface
{
    private readonly Interface _interface;

    public DerivedClass(Interface interface) => _interface = Interface;

    public int PropertyOne => _interface.PropertyOne;

    public string PropertyTwo => _interface.PropertyTwo;
}
```

Then you simply pass in an instance of base class into the constructor.

There's two advantages to this. Firstly it means you don't have to reimplement the logic in the constructor and the converter to deal with all 50 parameters. Resharper can in fact do all the logic for you.

Secondly, it means that you don't have to copy 50 parameters (approx 200 bytes in 32 bit runtime, 400 bytes in 64 bit) each time you create a derived type from the base class.

This may or may not be a suitable pattern, depending on your situation

Comment: Thanks, @YairHalberstadt. I've heard of Mixins but never actually got a chance to try them, seems like it's time!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no. Given the classes the way you've presented them, there is no compiler keyword or syntax sugar to make the mapping happen automatically.

The longer answer is: the fact that you're running into this problem in the first place is an indication that your classes are probably not structured in an optimal way. If you have the freedom to change the classes in the first place, you can probably get the results you're looking for.

For example, if you have 50+ constructor arguments that are always exactly the same and are used by a lot of different sub-classes, why not declare a single class that has all of those arguments and properties, and make the base class take one of those as a single constructor argument?

```
public DerivedClass(BaseClassArguments args) : base(args)
```

You might also want to reconsider whether it makes sense for your classes to use inheritance at all. For example, if you are creating all these child classes because they apply different logic to the data in the base class, then perhaps they should all implement an interface that has methods that take that data as an argument.

Or, you could make those classes take the "base" class as a constructor argument and keep it as a field or property, rather than extending the base class. This is known as using *composition* rather than inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'd recommend this, but you could use reflection to automatically map properties to constructor arguments.

This example shows how to construct a class using three properties to match the three constructor arguments, but it could just as easily map 50.

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string ToPascalCase(this string camelCase)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(camelCase)
            ? camelCase
            : camelCase.First().ToString().ToUpper() + camelCase.Substring(1);
    }
}

class BaseClass
{
    public string Able { get; set; }
    public int Baker { get; set; }
    public DateTime Candy { get; set;}

    static public DerivedClass CreateDerived(BaseClass source)
    {
        var constructor = typeof(DerivedClass).GetConstructors()[0];
        var parameters = constructor.GetParameters();
        var arguments = parameters.Select
            (
                param => source
                    .GetType()
                    .GetProperty(param.Name.ToPascalCase())
                    .GetValue(source, null)
            );
        var instance = constructor.Invoke(arguments.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("{0} arguments found", arguments.Count());
        return (DerivedClass)instance;
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(string able, int baker, DateTime candy)
    {
        Able = able;
        Baker = baker;
        Candy = candy;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var b = new BaseClass
        {
            Able = "Able!",
            Baker = 2,
            Candy = new DateTime(2018,10,31)
        };

        var d = BaseClass.CreateDerived(b);

        Console.WriteLine("Able={0} Baker={1} Candy={2}", d.Able, d.Baker, d.Candy);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3 arguments found
Able=Able! Baker=2 Candy=10/31/2018 12:00:00 AM
```

[Link to working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WVTGsl)

Comment: That's very brittle - if any parameter doesn't exactly match a property it will break. It's also pretty slow too...

Comment: @YairHalberstadt Agreed. That is why I don't necessarily recommend this solution. But it does answer the question.