# Parsing XML object to multiple classes with different logic

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have a lot of XML nodes generated by a 3rd party:

```
<node id='8440' name='nodeOne' property_two='7.22' sorting_index='20'/>
<node id='8440' name='nodeTwo' property_two='7.22' sorting_index='subItemThree;30;subItemTwenty;50'/>
...
```

Every attribute has the same type and meaning among all nodes except one named *sorting_index*. Usually, it contains an `int` indicating, well, object's sorting index. In the first node above sorting index is 20 for an object named "nodeOne".

Unfortunately, sometimes those nodes are just "carriers" of a sorting index for multiple subobjects. Looking into a second node given above, we can see that it provides sorting indeces for objects named "subItemThree" and "subItemTwenty" with values 30 and 50 respectively.

Im my approach, I created two classes with first being a representation of a node with simple sorting_index and second class being a representation of a node with the complicated sorting_index logic. Second class extended the first one and added a method to extract an array of sorting indeces from *SortingIndex* property's getter.
So what I did is I parsed everything to a base class (*SortingIndex* property is of `string` type) and then converted some of them to a derived class. I've described the logic behind this in another question: [Converting from base to derived object while having a huge constructor definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53054573/converting-from-base-to-derived-object-while-having-a-huge-constructor-definitio)

However, I was told that having such a conversion is not a good design approach. What are your suggestions? I feel like having 2 totally independent classes with absolutely same logic except for one property is an overkill.

Comment: so what wiil be the output ? could you plz show your desired output?

Comment: @ershoaib, sorry if I didn't make it clear in my question, but I don't actually need any output. I just need to store parsed representations of nodes as objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether one should inherit from the other you should consider whether the derived class is substitutable for the base class, see the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

If its not, you could try something like this with a common base class that has all the properties apart from the sort index.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; }
    public int Property2 { get; }

    public BaseClass(string prop1, int prop2)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class StringClass : BaseClass
{
    public int SortIndex { get; }

    public StringClass(string prop1, int prop2, int index) :
        base(prop1, prop2)
    {
        SortIndex = index;
    }
}

public class CollectionClass : BaseClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, int>  SortIndexes { get;}

    public CollectionClass(string prop1, int prop2, Dictionary<string, int> indexes) :
        base(prop1, prop2)
    {
        SortIndexes = indexes;
    }
}
```